# Bitcoin Api (only found 1)

Tags: bitcoin

I need to use a bitcoin api, and only have found CoinBox. The problem is that coinbox is limited to only a few sites and isnt open to everyone so I cant use it. Are there any good alternatives to coinbox.me? Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for APIs or other off-site resources are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually quite a few apis. First there is coinbase which is my favorite since they pay the transaction fees for transactions over 0.001 BTC and all internal transactions are absolutely free (and instant). You can see their api. (https://coinbase.com/docs/api/overview). What they lack is that it is hard to grab the TX id's and any other specific information. There is also blockchain.info which is the most feature full, but the downside is that you have to pay all of the fees and it can get to be very expensive. You can see the api. (https://blockchain.info/api). There are a lot more but the problem is that they are very buggy. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I will be looking at the blockchain api!

Comment: Ya, no problem. If you have any issues with these api's let me know.

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to use web wallets to create addresses. You can install your own bitcoin server/daemon and act like your own bank.

This is the place to start if you want to know how to do it (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page).

Bitcoin can be queried using JSON RPC methods. So if you are running a bitcoin daemon locally you can just query them. The documentation for the same is located at

**Running Bitcoin** - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

**API Reference** - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)

**API Call List** - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Hope this helps.